# Does PM2 Automatically Detects Apps for the Modules System?

Tags: node.js, pm2

In `PM2 v1.0`, it was mentioned that the new **Modules System** allows us to monitor application on a remote server. When I checked my [Keymetrics](https://app.keymetrics.io) dashboard, I discovered that there are already modules that are monitoring apps and data regarding `CPU` usage, `Memory`, etc.. Does PM2 automatically detects this when I monitored one of my apps?

I can recognized several apps (`MySQL` and `RabbiMQ`) that are being monitored, but I am confused because there are apps (`elastic`, `redis`, etc.) that I do not remember configured in my server (or I do not know they exists or perhaps pre-configured by a `ZendServer` installation).

Also note that I haven't upgraded pm2 to ver 1 in my server.

Specs.:

- pm2 v 0.15.10

Answer (score 0):

`PM2` does not automatically monitor apps in `Keymetrics` configured in a server unless the module `server-monitor` was installed in `PM2` and you enabled monitoring for a specific app . Most of the apps listed in `Keymetrics` only contains static dummy data.